# mdDatepicker broken with AngularJS 1.5.9 and 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-1.6

Angular 1.5.9 introduced very interesting performance upgrades:

```
$compileProvider.commentDirectivesEnabled( false ); // disable comment directives
$compileProvider.cssClassDirectivesEnabled( false ); // disable css class directives
```

I updated version of Angular in my app to `1.5.9-build.5158+sha.cc92da0` and later to `1.6.0-rc.1` to use above features. Everything except one detail works fine.
The thing which is broken is Angular Materials datepicker (`1.1.1`).

When you open datepicker it appears empty, but when you scroll it up a little all information appears. **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOWadZ)**

I spent some time fiddling around but I can't find the direct reason of such behavior.

Any help with fixing this bug will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled` set to `false` by default in Angular 1.6.

[More info.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15350)

To fix that problem I changed it to `true`:

```
.config( [ '$compileProvider', function ( $compileProvider ) {
  /* ... */
  $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled( true );
} ] )
```

Comment: nice find this was driving me crazy. Just to make the answer more clear, the `config` method is on the `angular.module('myModule', ['ngMaterial'])` object.